# Websphere MQ Queue depth in case of Multi Instanced enviornment

Tags: ibm-mq

How to get Websphere MQ Queue depth in case of Multi Instanced environment.

For a single instance we are getting a queue depth using the MQManager like this:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   private MQQueueManager createQueueManager() throws MQException {
        MQEnvironment.channel = channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = port;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = host;
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,   MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);
        return new MQQueueManager(manager);
    }
```

For Websphere MQ in multi-instancing environment how to perform the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either of these ways:

- Use a load balancer which is capable of routing the TCP connections based on the availability of the queue manager instances behind it, and connect to the address of the load balancer instead of directly to the queue manager.
- Use a Client Channel Definition Table to specify the parameters for the queue manager connection. You will need to configure a queue manager group containing the instances of your queue manager and connect using the CCDT:
  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ja11090_.htm

Comment: The situation at hand is that we do not have a Load Balancer in the zone where MQ is deployed. What is the mechanism to generate the CCDT files ?

Comment: You can define the records in the CCDT by creating client-connection channels on a queue manager. The CCDT file will be in the data directory of the QM in the @ipcc directory with name AMQCLCHL.TAB